# Children checkbox not selected on Parent checkbox selection in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, frontend

In a React project, certain records which are fetched from JSON are displayed. It also has checkbox, with Parent checkbox on the table head. My intention is when Parent checkbox is selected all children checkbox should be selected. I have also referred other posts but, none had been useful.So I tried with one solution but, didn't work. Please refer to code below.

```
const [checkedAll, setCheckedAll] = useState(false);

  // Function for Parent checkbox
  const selectAllCallback = (checked) => {
    setCheckedAll(true);
  };

  // Function for Children checkbox
  const checkBoxSelect = (checked, id) => {
    if (checkedAll) {
      checked = true;
    }
  };
```

This is what I am trying to implement. What could be the best solution to tackle this?. Please refer to codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-aryabhata-95o2sy?file=/src/Table.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked={checkedAll} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried but, didn't work. If you don't can you please update sandbox?

Comment: I thinks that's a whole logic you have to implement to handle these cases :

When checking the master checkBox is checked => check everything
When unchecking the master checkbox => uncheck every line
When unchecking a box after having checked the master => uncheck the master but keep the others checked.

You can achieve this by implementing new states and combinatory functions (maybe using the context api to avoid prop drilling)